# Change FreeBSD's fetch with aria2 or axel

Tags: freebsd

FreeBSD uses `FETCH` command in order to download source codes or binary packages it needs to compile or install.
If you are on slow connection like café or shared band this process become painful. `FETCH` can't resume in most cases and fails so as the process trying to install or  compile something.

I want to know if it is possible to use `aria2` or `axel` instead of `fetch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [man ports](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ports&sektion=7):

> ***fetch***   Fetch all of the files needed to build this port from the
>           sites listed in MASTER_SITES and PATCH_SITES.  See FETCH_CMD,
>           MASTER_SITE_OVERRIDE and MASTER_SITE_BACKUP.
>
> ....
>
> FETCH_CMD    Command to use to fetch files.  Normally fetch(1).

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/make.conf` and then add these lines:

```
FETCH_CMD=axel
FETCH_BEFORE_ARGS="-n 4 -a"
FETCH_AFTER_ARGS=
DISABLE_SIZE="yes"
```

Try to installing packages via ports, and see the difference.

Comment: The thing that i don't know is DISABLE_SIZE. What does it do?